# How do I keep RISC-V compliance?

Tags: riscv, instruction-set

I just had a discussion with a colleague about what RISC-V compliance actually means. We discussed the following topics in detail:

1. As far as I understood the idea, a processor is RISC-V compliant as long as it implements a RISC-V base instruction set and optionally one or more of the standard extensions. **Entirely**, not just partly. One might even define and implement own instructions (as brownfield or greenfield extensions) as long as they do not touch the base instruction set or any of the standard extensions. Guaranteeing this, the machine code generated by any RISC-V compliant compiler would run on my machine. That's the whole point of it, right?

   - The RISC-V ISA does not intend delayed branches. My understanding is that the definition whether branches are delayed or not is already part of the ISA and not a matter of implementation. Is this correct?
   - Assume that one wants to use RISC-V with delayed branches. Whether this is a good idea or not, let's just focus on the compliance question. In my opinion it were no longer RISC-V compliant to define and implement some of the existing branch/jump instructions of the **base instruction set** as delayed branches. The compilation of a RISC-V compliant compiler would no longer work on such a machine. One would be free to define **own** delayed branch instructions instead. Of course, as with any self-written extension, it cannot be expected that an arbitrary compiler would use such an instruction. Am I right?
2. According to the RISC-V specification, "the program counter pc holds the address of the current instruction." My interpretation of this sentence is that any jump/branch instruction refers to the address at which it is stored. Again, independent of the implementation. Example: Assume an implementation where the jump/branch instruction is executed a few cycles after it has been fetched. This would mean that PC has potentially increased already. It is therefore the implementation's task to somehow store the address of the jump/branch instruction. It is **not** the compiler's task to know about this delay and compensate for it by modifying the immediate that is to be added to the PC. Am I summarizing this correctly?

So, in a nutshell the short version of my questions:

1. Does RISC-V compliance mean that base integer instruction set and standard extension must neither be changed nor stripped?
2. Is the information whether a branch is delayed or not already part of the ISA?
3. Is the PC of RISC-V considered agnostic to any pipeline delay?

I consider an ISA in general to be agnostic to any implementation specifics. The counter-argument to what I claim is that one would have to tell the compiler about implementation specifics (delayed branches, PC behavior etc.) and that this could still be considered compliant with the ISA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert, but have implemented a few cores during the last 20 years. The key concept in your three part-questions are *completeness* and *user visibility*. To claim completeness means, in my opinion, that no part of a standard can be changed, nor stripped. However, it is a rare standard indeed if it has no dubious points and sections that may be interpreted differently by different people. In the specific case of RISC-V I would like to point to an aid to [indicate compliance](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-compliance), if you have not seen it already.

It would be good to have some real experts answering this question.

> 1. Does RISC-V compliance mean that base integer instruction set and standard extension must neither be changed nor stripped?

I have the same understanding as you. It does not make sense to claim a behaviour as defined in a standard, and then not honouring that standard.

> 2. Is the information whether a branch is delayed or not already part of the ISA?

Again I concur with you. Delayed branches is an exposed feature for users of a processor. Hence an ISA must specify the eventual existence of such branches, indeed, from page 15 of riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf:

> "Control transfer instructions in RV32I do not have architecturally visible delay slots."

Notice the wording, as long as your implementation does not expose any delay slot to a user, you can do as you want. And with a non-standard extension you are perfectly free to design instructions that have delay slots, you may even put RV32I instructions in those slots.

> 3. Is the PC of RISC-V considered agnostic to any pipeline delay?

Yes.